# How can I replace a UIViewController with a UISplitView Controller?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Mine is a normal viewcontroller application. When I click a button on this mainView, it adds a 2nd view(a different xib) as a subview to the mainView. I want this 2nd view to be replaced by a splitview. So it means I should replace the 2nd view controller with a UISplitViewController, isnt it?

Can I do that? Is it possible to add a splitviewcontroller's view like v add a viewcontroller's view?

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that, currently, the only *official* usage of `UISplitViewController` is as a *root* view controller of an application; Apple does not intend for it to be a child view controller. Apparently, this is due to bugs with handling rotation of the iPad, and may get fixed at a later date. So you should avoid adding a `UISplitViewController`'s view as a subview to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIViewController and then in the init:

```
UIViewController *left = ...;
UIViewController *right = ...;
UISplitViewController *splitVC = ...;
splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:left,right,nil];
self.view = splitVC.view;

return self;
```

Then just use this as a normal UIViewController.